# android program not running on eclipse

Tags: android-layout

I am a newbie in android and I have a source code downloaded but it is not running can anyone help me. There is no my cross signature but also my program is not running and I am unable to know the error output from logcat
this is my mainactivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TextView JsonSrc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_src);
       TextView JsonResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_result);
       /*
        * JSON:
        * {"id":12,"name":12,"status":"ok","volumes":[{"id":17592,"name":"root","status":"ok"}]}
        */
       final String customJSON = "{\"id\":12,\"name\":12,\"status\":\"ok\",\"volumes\":[{\"id\":17592,\"name\":\"root\",\"status\":\"ok\"}]}";
       JsonSrc.setText(customJSON);
       try {
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(customJSON);
   String myId = jsonObject.getString("id");
   String myName = jsonObject.getString("name");
   String myStatus = jsonObject.getString("status");
   String stringJsonResult = "id: " + myId + "\n"
        + "name: " + myName + "\n"
        + "status: " + myStatus;


   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("volumes");
   JSONObject arrayElement_0 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
   String ele0_id = arrayElement_0.getString("id");
   String ele0_name = arrayElement_0.getString("name");
   String ele0_status = arrayElement_0.getString("status");
   stringJsonResult += "\n\nArray Element 0 - \n"
        + "id: " + ele0_id + "\n"
        + "name: " + ele0_name + "\n"
        + "status: " + ele0_status;

   JsonResult.setText("\n" + stringJsonResult);

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
   }
}
```

This is my logcat output

```
08-24 10:01:56.662: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activityComponentInfo{com.mokshya.androidparse/com.mokshya.androidparse.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Please Help me.

Comment: seems like you have no coding error..there is an issue with your pc/machine..dont fedup..be positive..give me your machine configuration...is your emulator freezing ? or machine got stucked ? please upload new version of eclipse and android sdk..
if your emulator isn't working please try to debug with your android phone... in android emulator is slow but phone is fast..
in iphone emulator is fast phone is slow... tc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

That should give you something to start investigating.

This error means somewhere an object of type `TextView` is being cast to type `ViewGroup`. From the code that you have posted, I cannot see any such problems at one look. Could be an issue in your `activity_main.xml`. I hope your root tag is of type *Layout.